# how to declare global variable in sql

Tags: sql, database

I would like create a GLOBAL VARIABLE in a Sql script.
For my understanding using DECLARE I will be able to create just LOCAL variable.

Any idea how to create theem?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "global" variable? What do you want it to do that a local variable can't? Also, variable scope is defined within a SQL statement/block or a function/procedure; I'm not sure how the scope would apply to script. What kind of script is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming MS SQL Server, and assuming the MS definition of '[Global Variable](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tutorial/Global-variables)' you cannot.  If you need a variable to be accessable across multiple stored procedures, or ad-hoc queries, you will need some other way to hold the data: say a table which holds the variable for you.

**Note**: the hyperlink does not go to Microsoft, I could not find a copy of Microsoft's specific definition, but the website linked came close enough for this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create a table do hold the system wide data you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a scalar function that returns hard code value.
Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[APPID]()

RETURNS INT BEGIN 

    RETURN 1
```

To use:

```
SELECT [dbo].[APPID]()
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM ApplicationAccount WHERE AppID = dbo.APPID()
```